# How to Simply Dismiss Google Calendar Notification With Opera Browser

Tags: windows, notifications, opera, google-calendar

When I use Google Calendar with Opera browser, and I click on the "Close" or the "Snooze" button, it opens the dialog to *edit* the Event.  When I use Edge or Chrome, clicking on these buttons simply dismisses the notification.  How can I (as a user) make Opera+Calendar simply close the Notification instead of editing?

Note: I observe that with Chrome/Edge/Opera, clicking on the Notification's background will edit the Event. Clicking an notification button with Opera behaves as if the click passes through the button and clicks on the background.

Note 2: I'd prefer to dismiss the Notification with a mouse click. I'm aware that Win-Shift-V followed by Del will close a Notification. I often have multiple Notifications, and I'd like to close a specific Calendar notification.

[image: Calendar Alert]

Comment: Becasyou you mentions the Win key apparently you are using Opera for Windows. What version of Windows are you using? This notifications are desktop notifications (notifications center), right?

Comment: Windows 11 Pro, Version 22H2, Build 22621.1265.